# Alternating split of a given singly linked list

Tags: java, linked-list, interview-questions

> Write a function `AlternatingSplit()` that takes one list and divides its nodes to make two smaller lists `a` and `b`. The sublists should be made from alternating elements in the original list.
>
> Example: if the original list is `0->1->0->1->0->1`, then one sublist should be `0->0->0` and the other should be `1->1->1`.

This code is attributed to geeksforgeeks.  I'm looking for code review, optimizations and best practices.  Specifically, please let me know if the way I have used a private constructor in code is acceptable within coding standards, and if not, an alternative.

1. Why I don't extend or reuse: I am prepping for interviews, and interviewers explicitly want you to code, in my experience.  I request the reviewer to not insist on reusing, as I am aware in real life reusability is the right approach.  This does not work in interviews.
2. Why don't I use a `Util` class instead nesting method inside linked list?  That is because I need the `Node` to be an internal data structure. If I made a `Util` class, it would have no access to internal data structure and perform operations on the node's pointers.

```
final class AlternateSplitData<T> {
    private final AlternateSplit<T> evenLL;
    private final AlternateSplit<T> oddLL;
    
    public AlternateSplitData(AlternateSplit<T> evenLL,  AlternateSplit<T> oddLL) {
        this.evenLL = evenLL;
        this.oddLL = oddLL;
    }
    
    
    public AlternateSplit<T>  getEvenLL() {
        return evenLL;
    }
    
    public AlternateSplit<T> getOddLL() {
        return oddLL;
    }
}


public class AlternateSplit<T> {
    
    private Node<T> first;   // is private constructor the right thing to do ?
    
    private AlternateSplit(Node<T> first) {
        this.first = first;
    }
    
    public AlternateSplit(List<T> items) {
        add(items);
    }
    
    private void add(List<T> items) {
        Node<T> prev = null;
        for (T item : items) {
            Node<T> node = new Node<>(item);
            if (first == null) {
                first = prev = node;
            } else {
                prev.next = node;
                prev = node;
            }
        }
    }
    
    
    private static class Node<T> {
        private Node<T> next;
        private T item;
        
        Node(T item) {
            this.item = item;
        }
    }
    
    
    public AlternateSplitData<T> alternate() {
        Node<T> temp = first;
        Node<T> oddhead = null;
        Node<T> odd = null;
        Node<T> evenhead = null;
        Node<T> even = null;
        int count = 0;

        while (temp != null) {
            if (count % 2 == 0) {
                if (evenhead == null) {
                    evenhead = temp;
                    even = temp;
                } else {
                    even.next = temp;
                    even = temp;
                }
            } else {
                if (oddhead == null) {
                    oddhead = temp;
                    odd = temp;
                } else {
                    odd.next = temp;
                    odd = temp;
                }
            }
            count++;
            temp = temp.next;
        }

        if (even != null) {
            even.next = null;
        }
        if (odd != null) {
            odd.next = null;
        }

        return new AlternateSplitData<T>(new AlternateSplit<T>(evenhead), new AlternateSplit<T>(oddhead));
    }
    
    // size of new linkedlist is unknown to us, in such a case simply return the list rather than an array.
    public List<T> toList() {
        final List<T> list = new ArrayList<>();
        if (first == null) return list;
        
        for (Node<T> x = first; x != null; x = x.next) {
            list.add(x.item);
        }
         
        return list;
    }
    
    
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hashCode = 1;
        for (Node<T> x = first; x != null; x = x.next)
            hashCode = 31*hashCode +  (x.item == null ? 0 : x.item.hashCode());
        return hashCode;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        AlternateSplit<T> other = (AlternateSplit<T>) obj;
        Node<T> currentListNode = first; 
        Node<T> otherListNode =  other.first;
       
        while (currentListNode != null && otherListNode != null) {
            if (currentListNode.item != otherListNode.item) return false;
            currentListNode = currentListNode.next;
            otherListNode = otherListNode.next;
        }
        return currentListNode == null && otherListNode == null;
    }

}

public class AlternateSplitTest {
    
    @Test
    public void testEvenLength() {
        AlternateSplit<Integer> as1 = new AlternateSplit<>(Arrays.asList(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5));
        AlternateSplitData<Integer> list1 = as1.alternate();
        
        assertEquals(new AlternateSplit<Integer>(Arrays.asList(0, 2, 4)), list1.getEvenLL());
        assertEquals(new AlternateSplit<Integer>(Arrays.asList(1, 3, 5)), list1.getOddLL());
    }

    @Test
    public void testOddLength() {
        AlternateSplit<Integer> as2 = new AlternateSplit<>(Arrays.asList(0, 1, 2, 3, 4));
        AlternateSplitData<Integer> list2 = as2.alternate();
        
        assertEquals(new AlternateSplit<Integer>(Arrays.asList(0, 2, 4)), list2.getEvenLL());
        assertEquals(new AlternateSplit<Integer>(Arrays.asList(1, 3)), list2.getOddLL());
        
    }
    
    @Test
    public void testSingleElement() {
        AlternateSplit<Integer> as3 = new AlternateSplit<>(Arrays.asList(0));
        AlternateSplitData<Integer> list3 = as3.alternate();
        
        assertEquals(new AlternateSplit<Integer>(Arrays.asList(0)), list3.getEvenLL());
        assertEquals(new AlternateSplit<Integer>(Collections.EMPTY_LIST), list3.getOddLL());
        
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Having a list whose type is `AlternateSplitData<T>` makes it totally impractical to use.  It's a singly linked list.  I don't care that it came from an alternating splitting process.  I just want it to interoperate with any other code that works with linked lists.

`alternate()` seems to contain a lot of code for my taste.  In particular,

```
if (even != null) {
    even.next = null;
}
if (odd != null) {
    odd.next = null;
}
```

is totally superfluous.

I suggest naming variables like `oddTail` for clarity, and to adhere to Java capitalization conventions.

```
public AlternateSplitData<T> alternate() {
    Node<T> oddHead = null,  oddTail,
            evenHead = null, evenTail;

    if (first != null) {
        evenHead = evenTail = temp;
        if (first.next != null) {
            oddHead = oddTail = temp;
        }   
    }   
    if (oddHead != null) {
        boolean isEven = false;
        for (Node<T> temp = oddHead.next; temp != null; temp = temp.next) {
            if ((isEven = !isEven)) {
                evenTail = (evenTail.next = temp);
            } else {
                oddTail = (oddTail.next = temp);
            }
        }   
    }   
    return new AlternateSplitData<T>(evenHead, oddHead);
}
```

Comment: `if ((isEven = !isEven))` took me longer than usual to take it in. Seems like a nice trick after you fight the instinct that it 'looks wrong'. ;p

Answer (score 3):

All interviewers are different. As an interviewer I wouldn't care about irrelevant details. I'd be very disappointed however by the implementation of `alternate`:

- `oddhead` and `evenhead` do not belong here. They are properties of the `AlternateSplitData`, and should be initialized by constructor. Similarly, `AlternateSplitData` should export methods to add item to one of their lists.
- `count` is totally bogus. Doing `even, odd, even, odd...` doesn't call for increments and modulos.

That said, I'd expect something along the lines of

```
public AlternateSplitData<T> alternate(Node<T> begin) {
    AlternateSplitData<T> asd = new AlternateSplitData<T>();
    while (begin) {
        asd.addEven(begin);
        if ((begin = begin.next) == null) break;
        asd.addOdd(begin);
        begin = begin.next;
    }
    return asd;
}
```

with `addEven` and `addOdd` methods dispatching `add` to an appropriate list.

Answer (score 2):

I think @user50399 and @vnp have made some good suggestions already, so I will touch on two lighter issues...

1. The following comment is misleading:

   ```
   private Node<T> first;   // is private constructor the right thing to do ?

   private AlternateSplit(Node<T> first) {
       this.first = first;
   }

   public AlternateSplit(List<T> items) {
       add(items);
   }
   ```

   `Node<T> first` is not a constructor, and you have one private and public constructors each. Better to remove.
2. Your tests, at first glance, seem to imply that `alternate()` is actually splitting the list up into lists containing even and odd *numbers*. This is because the method name simply said `getEvenLL()` and `getOddLL()`. Furthermore, I get it that your implementation is simply doing a modulus with 2, hence the concept of 'odd' and 'even', but a layperson will simply read your test data as "0 is the *first* element, 1 is the *second*, etc." This gets even more confusing, since now they will be concluding that getting the odd *elements* should be `0, 2, 4`. Perhaps renaming the method as `getOddIndexedLL()` will be marginally better, and to use pseudo-random integers to minimize any confusion as to what the method is returning.